# How to inverse query using Artifactory Query Language?

Tags: artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

In Artfactory, I have a list of "repo" properties, some of which come with a "path" property. I need to find all items that do not match these properties. I was wondering if there was a way to structure my logic so that this could be done in one query.

Here's my current, broken logic:

```
curl -u $credentials \
-X POST https://my-artifactory-server.com/artifactory/api/search/aql \
-H content-type:text/plain -d 'items.find({ 
    "$and": [
        {"repo" : {"$neq" : "top_level_directory"}},
        { 
            "$and": [ 
                {"repo" : {"$neq" : "other_top_level_directory"}},
                {"path" : {"$nmatch" : "sub_directory/*"}}
            ]
        }
    ]
}).include("repo","path","name","size","modified")'
```

The issue with this is that while the "repo" property is unique, the "path" property is not. All subdirectories would thus be excluded from the query result.

Comment: Inversion can be made using De Morgan's laws. However, it is not clear what do you want to achieve. Please explain rigorously what do you want to find in the query and what is the original query that you want to inverse?

Comment: I would like to invert a query that finds all items in Artifactory that have the "repo" property "top_level_directory", OR the "repo" property "other_top_level_directory" and the "path" property "sub_directory/*".

This could look something like this: 
`or {
repo == "top_level_directory",
and {
repo == "other_top_level_directory",
path == "sub_directory/*"
}
}`

What I'm looking for is every item not found by this query. Artifactory, as far as I can tell, does not have NOT or NOR logic, which makes things more difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. AQL is like a logical clause and therefore we can structurize it.
I'm assuming the following is the original query:

```json
{
  "$or": [
    { "repo": { "$eq": "top_level_directory" } },
    {
      "$and": [
        { "repo": { "$eq": "other_top_level_directory" } },
        { "path": { "$match": "sub_directory/*" } }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
A - repo == top_level_directory
B - repo == other_top_level_directory
C - path =~ sub_directory/*
```

```
Original query:
A ∨ (B ∧ C)

Inversion:
¬(A ∨ (B ∧ C))
<=> (De Morgan)
¬A ∧ ¬(B ∧ C))
<=> (De Morgan)
¬A ∧ (¬B ∨ ¬C))
```

And the following query deduced:

```json
{
  "$and": [
    { "repo": { "$neq": "top_level_directory" } },
    {
      "$or": [
        { "repo": { "$neq": "other_top_level_directory" } },
        { "path": { "$nmatch": "sub_directory/*" } }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```